# How to optional update data on oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ALMAT"."PRODUCT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "PRICE" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(180 BYTE), 
    "CREATE_DATE" DATE, 
    "UPDATE_DATE" DATE, 
CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))
```

i want to update data in this table, this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATEPRODUCT(prod_id int, prod_name varchar2 default null, prod_price int default null) AS 
BEGIN
    
    
    update product
        set
        name = prod_name,
        price = prod_price,
        update_date = sysdate
        where id = prod_id;
        commit;
    
    
END UPDATEPRODUCT;
```

im using optional parameters, how can i update only 1 column? for example: only "NAME" or "PRICE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` (or `NVL`) to keep the current value when a `NULL` value is passed in (or the default is used):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATEPRODUCT(
  prod_id    PRODUCT.ID%TYPE,
  prod_name  PRODUCT.NAME%TYPE  DEFAULT NULL,
  prod_price PRODUCT.PRICE%TYPE DEFAULT NULL
)
AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE product
  SET   name        = COALESCE(prod_name, name),
        price       = COALESCE(prod_price, price),
        update_date = SYSDATE
  WHERE id = prod_id;
END UPDATEPRODUCT;
```

Also, do not `COMMIT` in a stored procedure as it prevents you from chaining multiple procedures together in a single transaction and rolling them all back as a block. Instead, `COMMIT` from the PL/SQL block that calls the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NVL function here. So your updated procedure would look alike -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATEPRODUCT(prod_id    int,
                                          prod_name  varchar2 default null,
                                          prod_price int      default null) AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE product
       SET name = NVL(prod_name, name),
           price = NVL(prod_price, price),
           update_date = sysdate
     WHERE id = prod_id;

    COMMIT;
    
EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
              RAISE;
END UPDATEPRODUCT;
```

Comment: Catching `OTHERS` is bad practice; and if you are just going to `RAISE` the exception again then it seems a pointless activity.

Comment: @MT0, I just use a generic statement as a hint to OP to use an EXCEPTION block in the proc. And I still think OTHERS is the best practice if used with correct statements.

Comment: It is bad practice as it will mask the errors so that you do not know they have been raised; you should catch specific errors individually and handle them individually then when a different error is raised your code fails immediately and you can debug it. The worst thing you can do is hide the error by catching all errors and then carry on as if it succeeds only to find a cascade of related failures due to corrupted/missing data.

Comment: Also, do not `COMMIT` in a stored procedure as it prevents you from chaining multiple stored procedures together in a transaction and then choosing to `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` them all as a block.